# "Your lab is in a failed state"

Tags: azure-lab-services

I have twice experienced that a lab ends up in a failed state. All I can do is remove and re-create the lab.

[image]

Is there anyway one can prevent this from happening? Or at least be able to recover the lab master VM?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting the issue! We're investigating the root cause right now. We'll keep you updated on the status here. Currently we have not yet identified a workaround.

Comment: As opposed to answering here, wouldn't it be better to suggest the OP ask on the proper support channel, which must exist on some MS site?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved! Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

We reached out to the Product Team and it appears this was a known issue which is now resolved.

Please try to create the lab again.

Here is a [blog post update](https://apac01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Fdevtestlab%2F2019%2F02%2F04%2Fclassroom-labs-users-may-not-be-able-to-create-labs-successfully%2F&data=02%7C01%7CGarg.Aman%40microsoft.com%7C41290fa10c15472046f108d68b23214f%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C636849380356835615&sdata=lgQ15ClND%2FLYHWu7YMC0jCglml%2BmSFUBEA0xGILWBeM%3D&reserved=0) for this.